# error while inserting row to sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "/": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO tab VALUES (1, /, /);`
is the error I'm getting when I try to insert row using query

`sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_TAB + " VALUES (" + tab.getTab() + ", " + tab.getPath() + ", " + tab.getHome() + ");");`
I don't understand what is wrong with the query, everything seems fine to me.

Comment: You need to put quotes around strings

Comment: Wow, I had no Idea... Been stuck onto this from last 1 hour and you just solved in a min. Thanks bro (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code instead.

```
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_TAB + " VALUES ('" + tab.getTab() + "', '" + tab.getPath() + "', '" + tab.getHome() + "');");
```

You should surround text values with quotes.